# Close URLCOnnection

Tags: java

How can I close HttpsURLConnection like this:

```
 HttpsURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(externalUrl);
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            return IOUtils.toString((con.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (con != null) {
                return IOUtils.toString((con.getErrorStream());
            }
        }
```

Comment: please check the answer . Hope it helps you

Comment: If you’re using Java 11 or later, you can use [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) instead.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I would like to mention that, the code in your question is not even compiling because of an extra bracket when you are doing `IOUtils.toString((con.getInputStream());` and `IOUtils.toString((con.getErrorStream());`

Now coming to your question of how to close the connection. Since, HttpsURLConnection does not implement Closeable interface, so putting it in try with resources block wont help you. **You need to close the connection in a finally block.**

This will serve your purpose:

```
    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    InputStream errorStream = null;
    try {
      URL url = new URL(externalUrl);
      con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      is = con.getInputStream();
      return IOUtils.toString(is, Charset.defaultCharset());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      if (con != null) {
        errorStream = con.getErrorStream();
        return IOUtils.toString(errorStream,Charset.defaultCharset());
      }
    } finally {
      if (is != null) {
        try {
          is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
      }
      if (errorStream != null) {
        try {
          errorStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
      }
      if (con != null) {
        con.disconnect();
      }
    }
```

Note- **There are some caveats using `disconnect`. Please read them [here](https://techblog.bozho.net/caveats-of-httpurlconnection/) .**

Lastly, a suggestion, please avoid using deprecated methods. The method `IOUtils.toString(inputStream)` is **deprecated** and instead you should use the `IOUtils.toString(inputStream,charset)`

Comment: You can use try-with-resources on the input stream. `disconnect()` should be avoided, as it interferes with connection pooling.